# Разный набор валидаций для одного и того же DTO

Tags: spring, rest, валидация, bean-validation

У меня есть вот такого рода DTO:

```
@Data
@UniqueField(fieldName = UniqueFields.EMAIL, message = "Указанный email занят!")
@UniqueField(fieldName = UniqueFields.USERNAME, message = "Указанное имя пользователя занято!")
public class UserProfileDTO {

    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Имя пользователя должно быть заполнено!")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Пароль должен быть заполнен!")
    private String password;

    @NotBlank(message = "Email должен быть заполнен!")
    @Email(message = "Не правильно введен email!")
    private String email;

}
```

Я бы хотел использовать его в разных методах своих контроллеров.

Например:

1. Мне может приходить заполненным только email - когда пользователь меняет свой email
2. Заполненным может быть только пароль - когда пользователь меняет пароль

Но в этом случае валидация срабатывает на пустые поля, котоыре мне не нужны в данный момент.

Вопрос:
Можно ли не создавая под каждый случай новое DTO указывать какие правила валидации нужно делать в каждый конкретный случай? Например, в методе:

```
@PutMapping("/{id}/email")    
public ResponseEntity<Set> changeEmail(@PathVariable(value = "id") User user,
                                           @RequestBody
                                           @Valid
                                                   UserProfileDTO userProfileDTO,
                                            Errors errors) throws ValidationErrorsException {
        ...
    }
```

Производить валидацию только email, но пропускать проверку username и password.

Пробовал использовать аннотацию @JsonView, но это влияет только на заполненность объекта, при вызове метода. Но валидация на пустые поля, все равно происходит.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спринг имеет в своём распоряжении аннотацию `@Validated`, которая позволяет "управлять стратегией" валидации с помощью интерфейсов/классов маркеров.

Маркер:

```
public interface ValidationMarkers {
    interface Strategy1 {};
    interface Strategy2 {};
}
```

DTO:

```
public class Employee {

    @NotBlank(groups = {ValidationMarkers.Strategy1.class})
    private String firstName;
    @NotBlank(groups = {ValidationMarkers.Strategy2.class})
    private String lastName;
    @Min(value = 18, groups = {ValidationMarkers.Strategy1.class, ValidationMarkers.Strategy2.class})
    private Integer age;
}
```

Контроллер:

```
public ResponseEntity<?> addEmployee1(@Validated(ValidationMarkers.Strategy1.class) Employee employee)
public ResponseEntity<?> addEmployee2(@Validated(ValidationMarkers.Strategy2.class) Employee employee)
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало! Можно еще вопрос тут задать: Можно ли как-нибудь в Jackson указать аннотацию, чтобы в пустые поля не преобразовывались в JSON? Например, когда я пишу new ResponseEntity(employee, HttpStatus.OK)? чтобы пустые поля в employee не попали в тело ответа в виде JSON?

Comment: Кажется нашел, @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY). Правильно?

Comment: serodv, можно вас попросить посмотреть еще вот этот вопрос в продолжение начатой здесь темы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1022149/%d0%9c%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-dto-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b2-rest-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-spring