# Много DTO или много аннотаций в REST приложении на Spring?

Tags: json, spring, аннотации, dto

Какой подход лучше использовать:

1. Делать несколько видов DTO под разные случаи, например: форма регистрации, форма профиля, форма редактирования профиля, администрирование пользователей
2. Делать много аннотаций у одного класса DTO, для управления разным составом полей в разных ситуациях: @JsonView, @Validated, @JsonInclude
3. Комбинировать оба подхода, разделив на уровне DTO области взаимодействия: Собственный профиль, Другой пользователи, Администирование пользователя и аннотациями управлять разными ситуациями редактирование email, редактирование пароля пользователем

В случае только DTO получаем большое количество дублирущего кода.
В случае только аннотаций и одного DTO боюсь цепочки аннотаций в какой-то момент станут не читаемыми.

Какой лучший подход при работе с DTO для одного и того же объекта?

Comment: Оффтоп: Как тебе в целом работа со Спрингом и Hibernate? Как я помню, ты с июня начал учить

Comment: antonio112009 так получилось, что я еще и Vue.js+Nuxt.js учу параллельно. Сначала начал с teamleaf, а в итоге пришел к Nuxt.js. Как бы это дико не звучало, я начал изучать Spring для конкретного личного проекта))) Учитывая, что Java это самый близкий мне язык, Spring мне нравится, а когда начинаю узнавать всякие примочки, типа аннотаций указанных в вопросе, все становится так легко. Сейчас пришел к тому, что Spring буду использовать как RestApi на стороне сервера, а весь frontend отдам Vue.js. В общем мне нравится)))

Comment: antonio112009 а по теме вопроса не добавишь комментария?)))

Comment: Я не знаю как выглядит DTO. Может потому что я делаю Spring MVC, а не Spring REST Api(((

Comment: Antonio112009 А как же передаешь объекты в шаблон? Прямо сущности напрямую?

Comment: То, что я скажу, это для MVC подходит. Беру репозиторий(crudrepository), с помощью Service сохраняю/достаю/обновляю объекты в БД, а с помощью контроллера, вывожу их на странице

Comment: Лучше делать много DTO(имхо), так код становится красивее и понятнее. Если много DTO не нравится, могу предложить такой подход - сделать пару DTO для кейсов где передается больше всего данных, а остальные случаи парсить вручную. Spring включает в себя Jackson(если данные в json), это не должно быть проблемой.

Comment: Anton Sorokin, сделал несколько общих DTO профиль, пользователь, пользователь для администрирования. И хотел использовать профиль для разных случаев, когда пользователь  сам работает со своим профилем: меняет email, меняет пароль, регистрируется, получает все данные своего профиля. Но столкнулся с проблемой, как наприме в случае изменения email не сериализовать в JSON поле пароль и id, ведь мне для смены пароля, нужны только поля username и email. Не знаете аннотацию в Jackson которая бы позволяла бы в разных методах запрещать разные поля для сериализации?

Comment: Anton Sorokin, Или все же лучше сделать DTO: UserPassword, UserEmail, UserProfile, UserRegistration? И не напрягать себя с кучей аннотаций?

Comment: @AlexanderLopatin я уже написал, можно парсить вручную. Специальными методами, `getJsonString()`, `getJsonObject()`, `getJsonNumber()`.